# telegram bot не распознает все сообщения пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

суть кода в том чтобы когда пользователь после того как ввел "перерыв" писал + или конец и ему через некоторое время выводило "перерыв окончен", но этого не происходит и сразу выводит "напоминаю что перерыв окончен"

```
breakWord = ['перерыв', 'пауза']
breakEnd = ['конец', '+']

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def text(message: types.Message):
    if message.text in breakWord:
        await message.answer("перерыв")
        if message.text in breakEnd:
            time.sleep(15)
            await message.answer("перерыв окончен")
        else:
            time.sleep(16)
            await message.answer("напоминаю что перерыв окончен")
```

Comment: ну логично, ведь условие с окончанием перерыва вложено в условие с началом перерыва

Comment: можно добавить асинхронный сон, import asyncio и после заменить time.sleep() на await asyncio.sleep()